# How to keep UILabel up to date with data model

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UIViewController` subclass, and for now my code is something like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     myLabel.text = "\(DataModel.varialbleExampleData)"
  }
}
```

But, here, variableExampleData is a variable, and may change over time, so how can I update the label whenever it changes ?

PS: I'm sorry if this question sounds really silly or obvious

Comment: kvo , notificationCenter or rxswift

Comment: Another *possible* way is to use delegates - this depends on the details of how `variableExampleData` is updated.

Comment: you can use local notifications, delegates or observable objects using RXswift.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a really primitive question. A little research into basic iOS concepts can help you with solving this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `NotificationCenter` to post a `Notification` whenever the data model changes. Then added an observer on my controller

Answer (score 2):

if you have this data in your view controller, you can use `didSet`. So it it changes text every time you set your data, as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!
  var data: DataModel? {
      didSet {
          myLabel.text = "\(data.variableExampleData)"
      }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```